# Interaction between JavaScript and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, javascript, html, winforms

i have a Windows Forms application, which uses a Webbrowsercontrol to display a dynamically generated Htmlpage. Is there a possibility to interact with the jscode of the page? For example if i have have the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ReturnValue()
{
var output;
output ='test';
return output;
}
</script>
```

Would there be a possibility to receive "test" in my application (not trough url)?

Comment: Maybe something like `InvokeScript` could help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript.aspx Just guessing, never done it.

Comment: Yes, that would be usefull if i wanted to execute a jsfunction from my application, but the function is called f.e. on the onclickevent of a button (so i dont have any authority when it occures) and i want the result. I dont want to call a fuction, a ionly want the result

Comment: Maybe make the variable you want have a bigger scope, and then write a method that returns it... then call that? Might be a better way, but that sounds like it would work.

Comment: Thanks... to simple to think about that. Tyvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible using InvokeScript on the browser control; see this article for more information: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127356/Calling-JavaScript-function-from-WinForms-and-vice